# Cannot execute gdalwarp in a Python notebook

Tags: python, gdal, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

I try to reproject a raster using gdalwarp.

To do so I use the subprocess package of Python3 :

```py
command = [
    'gdalwarp',
    map_raster,
    map_raster_proj,
    '-t_srs', 'ESRI:54009'
]
print(' '.join(command))
    
kwargs = {
   'args' : command,
   'cwd' : os.path.expanduser('~'),
   'stdout' : subprocess.PIPE,
   'stderr' : subprocess.PIPE,
   'universal_newlines' : True
}
    
with subprocess.Popen(**kwargs) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line)
```

unfortunately I get the following error :

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
> ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
> ESRI:54009

When I run the command directly from my terminal It works flowlessly.

I imagine that I have some environment parameter missing or pointing to the wrong direction but I don't know where to start.

Any idea where I should check differences between the two execution env?

**EDIT**

I run Jupyter notebook from a company cloud interface, I have 0 idea of the installation, I have 0 right to access it. It's running on linux AWS instances.

several test that I performed :

```py
!gdalwarp --version
```

give me the same result in the terminal and the jupyter notebook : *GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28*

```py
!printenv | grep PROJ_LIB
```

I have nothing in the terminal env and *PROJ_LIB=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasterio/proj_data* in the notebook.
If I run this command in another notebook I get 0 errors and the `PROJ_LIB` variable is not set. I think my install of rasterio and gdal are coliding is it possible ?

Comment: You haven't got PROJ_LIB set or it's set incorrectly. Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/371488/edit) and specify what OS you use, how you installed gdal and jupyter (pip, pipenv, conda, virtualenv, something else), how you run jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who may fall here, rasterio and gdal python bindiing are not supposed to live in the same notebook [ref](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html). So rasterio was changing my PROJ_LIB env variable